# Ho do I prevent Passenger Standalone/nginx from removing double slashes?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, passenger

I am trying to run a Sinatra app with Passenger Standalone. The app takes a URL in the URL like this:

```
get "/url/*" do |url|
  "URL: #{url}"
end
```

Apparently nginx reduces consecutive slashes to only one. When I call `/url/http://example.com` it returns: `URL: http:/example.com`. When I run this without Passenger in front of it, it works perfectly.

Comment: There is none. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passenger Standalone's Nginx comes preconfigured and apparently is not meant to be customized. So I either have to set up a separate Nginx with `merge_slashes off` for this app or find another solution. I will take this as an opportunity to try [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/). :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `/url/http://example.com` is colliding with the rules for proper URLs:

According to [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt), 3.3. HTTP:

```
Within the <path> and <searchpart> components, "/", ";", "?" are
reserved.  The "/" character may be used within HTTP to designate a
hierarchical structure.
```

I would encode the 'http://example.com' rather than attempt to pass it as part of the path.